# Is referencing and modifying Game1 bad practice?

Tags: c#, xna

I need to change multiple Game1 variables from a different class. I have been doing it like this:

```
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        public int test1;
        public int test2;
    }


    public class Player
    {
        public Player(Game1 game)
        {
            game.test1 = 5;
            game.test2 = 10;
        }
    }
```

Is this bad practice, and if so is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is this bad practice, and if so is there another way to do this?

Yes and no.  It's often appropriate to modify state in one type from another type.

That being said, using two public fields to do this is something I would consider bad practice.  At a minimum, you should switch these to properties.  If "test1" and "test2" are related values, and always changed together, providing a single public method would be appropriate for setting these.

The downside to using public fields, as shown, is that you have no means of validating the values.  It's entirely possible for anybody (including `Player`) to set your fields to inappropriate values.  There are also versioning issues if you're sharing your code (changing to properties is an API breaking change, for example).

Any state (variables) you want to have be changed by other classes should always be exposed in a way that your class can control.  Properties or methods allow you to do this.  Even if this isn't required now, designing for the future is a better practice.

Comment: As a pragmatic summary to this answer, you could try a number of things: Exposing `SetTest1()` and `SetTest2()` (or making them properties) is the most basic solution, but you could also take a number of other approaches, such as generating a small-scale `Message` structure which `Game1` accepts, containing the values, and so on. The big concerns are *when* and *by whom* values need changing, so design around those concerns.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just glad you're not using a singleton, or making everything `static`.

It's perfectly fine practice to pass around references to a "parent" object: makes the dependency clear.

However, I don't recommend simply passing around `Game1` references everywhere. Since games are typically relatively large/complex in terms of the objects they contain, it can make the dependency / intended access per object unclear (since now every object can touch everything in the game).  It can sometimes make more sense to logically split up your objects into parent containers:

```
public class Game1
{
    public readonly PlayerData playerData;
    public readonly EnemyData enemyData;
    //...
}
```

And have more tightly controlled access through these containers. Again it depends on your scope / size.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements, another option could be to store these variables in a static class, as static objects.  They would then be accessible from all classes, as long as they are part of the same project.

For example:

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static int test1;
    public static int test2;
}
```

Usage:

```
public class Player
{
    public Player()
    {
        Helper.test1 = 5;
        Helper.test2 = 10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It goes against [information hiding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding) which is one of the fundamental tenets of OOP. A class should in general be responsible for managing its own state, rather than delegate, or worse, share this responsibility with others. This is just a guideline and should be followed with proper judgement.

In the abstract this is the penalty you're paying:

- You're introducing a two-way rather than one-way binding between
  Game1 and the other class. This makes your design harder to reason
  about.
- You're sharing responsibility for these fields with another class. This means you cannot simply look at the Game1 class to determine how
  these fields can change, but rather in an arbitrary number of
  classes.
- Every class that will have a reference to Game1 will also be able to change these variables. This means that the more classes you have,
  the harder it will become to reason about how these variables can
  change.
- Since these variables can now be used by every class that can access Game1, removing them or changing their type becomes very
  difficult, because now you have to change all these other classes as
  well.

OOP is all about dividing a complex process into separate roles that can be easily reasoned about in isolation. Public state means shared state, and the more is shared between roles, the blurrier they become.

There are cases where public fields can make sense. For example, a simple 3D Point class could look like this:

```
class Point { public int X; public int Y; public int Z; }
```

This is ok because the class doesn't have any internal logic; it's just a container and it contains only these three closely related values. An example of such a class is the [Vector2 class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.vector2_members.aspx) in XNA, which exposes its state (X and Y) as public fields.